# What is the difference between this usage of pointer (a:=&A; a) and (b:=B; &b)

Tags: pointers, go

Can't understand following behavior. Difference of `d1 := &data{1}; d1` and `d2 := data{1}; &d1`. Both are pointer, right? But they behave differently. Whats happening here

```
package main

import "fmt"

type data struct {
    value int
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]*data)
    d1 := &data{1}
    m["d1"] = d1 // Here putting &{1}
    d1 = &data{2}
    fmt.Println(m["d1"])
    // &{1}

    d2 := data{1}
    m["d2"] = &d2 // Here putting &{1}
    d2 = data{2}
    fmt.Println(m["d2"])
    // &{2}
}
```

What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all about use and [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) of values vs pointers.

In both cases, `m[something]` holds an address to a `data`.
However, the important distinction is what `d1` and `d2` are.

#### d1 is of type `*data`:

The **value** of `d1` is a pointer. When we assign `&data{...}` to `d1`, this changes the value of `d1` to be a pointer to the new struct.

Since you are assigning, or changing the **value** of `d1`, the map still holds the old value.

```
d1 := &data{1}
fmt.Printf("d1    value: %p\n", d1)
// d1    value: 0x10410020

d1 = &data{2}
fmt.Printf("d1    value: %p\n", d1)
// d1    value: 0x10410024
```

As you can see: the address in memory that `d1` is pointing to has changed. You are storing the value `0x10410020` in the map, so even if you change `p1` to point to another address, the pointer inside the map still points to the original location.

The pointers look like:

```
m["d1"] -----> data{1}

d1      -----> data{2}
```

#### d2 is of type `data`:

In the case of `d2`, you are storing the **address** of the variable `d2`. On assignment, we change the value of `d2`, but its address does not change.

```
d2 := data{1}
fmt.Printf("d2    address: %p\n", &d2)
// d2    address: 0x10410028

d2 = data{2}
fmt.Printf("d2    address: %p\n", &d2)
// d2    address: 0x10410028
```

Since this address `0x10410028` is what you are storing in the map, it is pointing to the value of `d2` which changes on assignment.

The pointers in this look like (they're both pointers to the same area of memory. Sorry, it's hard to draw arrows in ascii):

```
m["d2"] -----\
             data{2}
d2      -----/
```

Comment: But, in both cases, I am assigning `*data` type. Right?

Comment: You definitely are. Give me a minute, I'll try and rephrase my answer better.

Comment: I would say this is about taking address to composite literals.

Comment: It doesn't matter if we're assigning `&data{1}` or some random variable of type `*data`. The important part is that assignments don't change the variable's address, they change the value. So really, it's about pointer vs value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was messing things with experience of c and Python. Go is more consistent and plain.